# Combining regexes using a loop in Perl 6

Tags: raku

Here I make a `regex` manually from `Regex` elements of an array.

```perl6
my Regex @reg =
  / foo /,
  / bar /,
  / baz /,
  / pun /
  ;

my $r0 = @reg[0];
my $r1 = @reg[1];

my Regex $r = / 0 $r0 | 1 $r1 /;

"0foo_1barz" ~~ m:g/<$r>/;
say $/;  # (｢0foo｣ ｢1bar｣)
```

How to do it with `for @reg {...}`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a variable contains a regex, you can use it without further ado inside another regex.

The second trick is to use an array variable inside a regex, which is equivalent to the disjunction of the array elements:

```
my @reg =
  /foo/,
  /bar/,
  /baz/,
  /pun/
  ;

my @transformed = @reg.kv.map(-> $i, $rx { rx/ $i $rx /});

my @match =  "0foo_1barz" ~~ m:g/ @transformed /;

.say for @match;
```

Comment: That's simply marvelous! Though I have a question: `say @transformed.perl` gives `[rx/ $i $rx /, rx/ $i $rx /, rx/ $i $rx /, rx/ $i $rx /]`. So does that mean that the values will be evaluated every time the regex is used?

Comment: @EugeneBarsky Regex.perl simply produces the string with which the regex was declared, no more, no less. I haven't done any performance analysis on the resulting regexes.

Answer (score 3):

```
my @reg =
  /foo/,
  /bar/,
  /baz/,
  /pun/
  ;

my $i = 0;

my $reg = @reg
  .map({ $_ = .perl; $_.substr(1, $_.chars - 2); })
  .map({ "{$i++}{$_}" })
  .join('|');

my @match = "foo", "0foo_1barz" ~~ m:g/(<{$reg}>) /;

say @match[1][0].Str;
say @match[1][1].Str;

# 0foo
# 2baz
```

See [the docs](https://docs.perl6.org/language/regexes#Regex_Interpolation)

Edit: Actually read the docs myself. Changed implicit eval to $() construct.

Edit: Rewrote answer to something that actually works

Edit: Changed answer to a terrible, terrible hack

Comment: Unable to parse expression in metachar:sym<assert>; couldn't find final '>' .../test.p6:13. Line 13 is the last from your code: `>/;`

Comment: Regex object coerced to string (please use .gist or .perl to do that)
  in block  at combine4.p6 line 11

Comment: Not a problem of my code here. Apparenly you are doing somehing along the lines of

    say "$rx";

Comment: Can't find the error. :( Could I please ask you to include in your answer the whole working program?

Comment: I overlooked you were using regex-literals in your array. Use strings and it works.

Comment: The whole idea of this question was to do it with regexes, not strings.

Comment: Well, here you go. But I don't like that. Not at all. I have yet to find a better way yet though.

Comment: You mean, you don't like the idea of combining regexes?

Comment: No. I don't like manipulating the .perl it in order to combine the regex. But luckily moritz++ below knows a better way.

Comment: In the current solution it seems `@reg` elements are coerced to Str. If I put a restriction `my Regex @reg`, I get the following message: `Type check failed in assignment to @reg; expected Regex but got Str ("/ foo /")`